# Excel, giving data labels to only the top/bottom X% values

Tags: excel, charts

I have a simple line chart that I've added data labels to:

[image: Chart]

But I don't want all those labels. I only want the top and bottom 10% (arbitrary number) values to be shown. For example, in the picture I'd only want the labels for 51, 54, 57, 61, 66, 68, 74 to show. I can manually delete the other labels but the chart data changes dynamically over time. Is there a method for accomplishing this? The text in those labels is a placeholder right now and will eventually be 6-10 characters long, at which point having all those labels will just be a complete mess.

I'm not real confident in VBA so I'd only like to fall back on that as a last resort.

**Edit:** Thanks to Scott for his insightful answer. It works perfectly with a manually populated Data Labels column. However, some jury rigging is needed if one wants to populate it dynamically. I used the following formula to populate it:

```
=IF(OR(O1=LARGE($O$1:$O$30,1),O1=LARGE($O$1:$O$30,2),O1=LARGE($O$1:$O$30,3)),O1,"")
```

Basically, it copies cell values from column O to column P if the value in O is the top 1st, 2nd, or 3rd value in the list. If it's not any of those, it leaves the cell blank. But even if a cell is visually blank, Excel's charting functions interprets the value as 0 if there is a formula in the cell. This means the entire bottom of the graph has repeated data labels of "0%". To solve this I set the value of the FALSE parameter as a negative number and then changed the minimum value on the graph from automatic to 0. This leaves the unfit values below the bottom of the chart, out of visible range.

Comment: you could use picture links to cells containing the labels you want (you could set up formulas to get those cells in a neat order), but then you'd be stuck adjusting them each month to fit the right spot on the chart, which is less manual then deleting out the labels you don't want, but still manual. Other than that, I can't think of Non-VBA solution that is any better.

Comment: I don't think there is a non-VBA method. This link may help get you started though http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914813

Comment: Love the answer... a simplification that I found is to use `NA()` in the `FALSE` section of your `IF` statement.  Charts in Excel ignore those, so you don't need to set work-arounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AHA!

Just when I thought there was no non-VBA solution other than picture links, my ingenuity came through :)

Here is what you can do, in stages:

1) Create a data set next to your original series column with only the values you want labels for (again, this can be formula driven to only select the top / bottom *n* values). See column D below.

[image]

2) Add this data series to the chart and show the data labels.

3) Set the line color to No Line, so that it does not appear!

4) *Volia!* See Below!

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I can foresee an issue with this based on something I just ran across trying to work something else out but I'll work at it. Maybe you have a solution for the issue. I have the X axis reversed as you can see in the OP's picture (49 is the last value in the list but the first item on the chart). When I add a second series to the same chart the axis is not reversed for the second series, only the first. I couldn't figure out how to surmount that problem.

Comment: Derp, I'll just reverse the list rather than the chart. The list is only there for chart values anyway and is not actually read/printed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome. That was kind of a fun process to figure out!

Comment: Well, things didn't turn out as well as hoped. But I did manage to jury rig it together. See OP for edit.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this for a pie chart?